# Socket.io not calling connect event in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, socket.io

I have an application which uses socket.io to communicate with the server. In all browsers (i.e. Google Chrome, Firefox, etc.) except IE, the connect event is triggered. See definition below.

```
var socket = io.connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337');

socket.on('connect', function () { 
    //code here 
});
```

For some reason, in IE8 this event doesn't get fired. Is there something different I need to do to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your JS console shows an "Access is Denied" exception. If so, have a look at:

[NodeJS-socket.io getting "Access is Denied" Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594913/nodejs-socket-io-getting-access-is-denied-exception)